# Chartjs Plugin Annotation does not work (it is registered)

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation

### Box annotation wont render even though the configuration is correct

---

*chartjs version: 3.6.0*

*chartjs-plugin-annotation version: 1.0.2*

---

The plugin is registered like this:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
Chart.register(annotationPlugin);
```

And I'm using the plugin as a constant that I add to the graph configuration:

```
plugins = {
            autocolors: false,
            annotation: {
                annotations: {
                    box1: {
                        type: 'box',
                        yMin: 2,
                        yMax: 4,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(221, 29, 33, 0.3)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    },
                    box2: {
                        type: 'box',
                        yMin: 0,
                        yMax: 2,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(251, 206, 7, 0.3)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    },
                    box3: {
                        type: 'box',
                        yMin: -2,
                        yMax: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(92, 171, 42, 0.3)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    },
                    box4: {
                        type: 'box',
                        yMin: -4,
                        yMax: -2,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.3)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                    },
                },
            },
        };
```

I'm rendering the graph as a base64 string so that I can turn it into a static image. The data is plotted but the boxes are not. It was working two weeks ago and now it isn't.

Comment: Not reproducable, seems to be working just fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-panka-wubnq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue